# Why are the dead-time in IRF boot-strap gate driver ICs relatively long?

Tags: gate-driving

Why are the dead-time in IRF gate-driver ICs like [IR2109](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/ir2109.pdf) relatively long?<sup>1</sup> I can be interpreting the data-sheet wrong too.

The IR2109 has a dead-time of 540ns. For IGBTs that dead-time are not relatively long. But if you take into consideration the driving currents of this IC (+120mA/-250mA) this seems more acceptable for MOSFETs, in my case a IRF740 that has specified switching times of less than 100ns.

So, what I'm getting wrong?

---

<sup>**1** Yes, you can generate the dead-time in the controller and use dual input like IR2110 (that has so much driving current compared to the IR2109), but I want reduced space (8PDIP), and I have only one signal per half-bridge leg, so I want drivers that can generate the dead-time and other switch signal.</sup>